# Поиск дочерних объектов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создаю префабы и для замены их компонентов использую

```
    var textMesh = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    textMesh.text = Score.ToString();

    Логика замены компонента на другой;
```

Проблема в том что если у меня есть два или больше префаба , то код не работает нормально.
Думаю,программа находит дочерний объект,но только первый.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html

Comment: А какова нужда для создания префаба из кода в объекте? Не проще сделать объект с уже настроенными префабами и скрипт содержащий требуемые связи. При необходимости можно управлять видимостью в префабе отдельных компонентов. Обычно этого достаточно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на поверхности. Используйте GetComponent**s**InChildren

```
var textMeshes = GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

foreach (var tm in textMeshes )
  tm.text = Score.ToString();
```